# Iterator, ListIterator and List

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

I have encountered a problem that I cannot quite figure out.
Would be super if you guys could help me out =)

I have a Lobby.Class that has a draw() Method:

```
public void draw() {
    //USE ITERATOR TO DRAW
    Iterator<Player> itr = players.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Player player = itr.next();
        int off = players.indexOf(player); //THE CORRECT HEIGHT
        player.draw(off);
    }
}
```

Note that this is a server/client game

The Lobby.Class has also 1 method called addPlayer()

```
public void addPlayer(String _playerName, String _class, String _string_id) {

    int _id = Integer.parseInt(_string_id);

    //CREATE THE NEW PLAYER
    Player new_player = new Player(x, y, _id, _playerName, _class);

    //IF THIS PLAYER IS ME
    if(new_player.getID() == id) {

        me = new_player;

    } else {

        //TELL THE NEW PLAYER I EXIST
        ClientValue.getClient().iExist(_id);

                    //THIS WILL SEND TO CLIENT THAT WILL SEND TO THE SERVER
                    //THAT WILL LOOK FOR THE ID AND SEND TO CLIENT OF THAT ID
                    //AND THE CLIENT WILL SEND TO LOBBY UPDATE PLAYERS()
    }

    players.add(new_player);

    chat.appendChat(chat.joinString(_playerName, _class));
}
```

The Lobby.Class has also 1 method called updatePlayers()

```
public void updatePlayers(String _playerName, String _class, String _string_id) {

    //THIS IS CALLED WHEN THE SERVER TELLS THIS PLAYER
    //ABOUT OTHER PLAYERS

    int _id = Integer.parseInt(_string_id);

    //CREATE THE NEW PLAYER
    Player new_player = new Player(x, y, _id, _playerName, _class);
    players.add(new_player);

}
```

Now my problem is the **players** List, when I enter the lobby `addPlayer()` will Run at the same time when 2 players join, or when the `updatePlayers()` are run with `addPlayer()`

The Exception i get is: **ConcurrentModificationException**

I am missing two methods, 1 for **adding players** with an Iterator if possible, 1 for **removing players**. So that I wont get the error for modifying the players List while going trough it or adding/removing it.

I have tried puzzling around with Iteror and ListIterator, but as I have never used them before, I am not sure what to do. I need some advice on how to do this.
Many thanks in advance =)

**Solution:**

```
private List<Player> players = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Player>());

    public synchronized void playersList(String cmd, Player _player) {

    Iterator<Player> itr = players.iterator();

    if(cmd.equals("draw")) {

        while(itr.hasNext()) {

            Player player = itr.next();
            int off = players.indexOf(player);
            player.draw(off);
        }

    } else if(cmd.equals("add")) {

        players.add(_player);

    } else if(cmd.equals("remove")) {

        players.remove(_player);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.*". You can't avoid it, [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: ok, but what if i initialize a Iterator at the top of my class, then use that iterator to add and remove, would that work. Also I noticed there is no add method with Iterator, does that mean I have to use ListIterator?

Comment: youst saw your link, I will see if I find a solution.

Comment: To avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown, use iterator's own methods. If you use `remove()` method of `List` anyway, the exception will be kept throwing and to me, I always use `ListIterator`.

Comment: Thx a lot for clearing things out =) will try that and post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronise access to the list, allowing only one thread to access the list at a time.

You could use a `synchronized` block around each access point (including the entire paint method) or you could wrap the player list in a thread safe list using [`Collections#synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) or, instead of an iterator, you could use the `toArray` method of players

```
Player[] arrayOfPlayers = players.toArray(new Player[players.size()]);
```

You are still going to `synchronized` the this call, but your only locking one line, not a whole loop

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. But the only thread that talks to the Lobby.Class is the Client.Class. So only one thread, do I still need to Synchronize or use Thread Safe list? sry for all the questions.

Comment: Well, actually, it looks like two threads are accessing your list, otherwise you wouldn't have a concurrent modification exception. You can't change the list while you are iterating it. You need to synchronise acces so that you are either updating it or iterating it, not both at the same time

Comment: Why not use a CopyOnWriteArrayList in this case?

Comment: @Mik378 Nice idea (I learnt something today), it does add a lot of overhead though, would a `synchroniedList` be faster??

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you have few writing and a lot of reading threads, CopyOnWriteArraylist would be perfect. Inversely, if fact of writing is very frequent, performance would be decrease due to the potential huge arraycopy usage. So the synchronizedList could effectively be used instead. Anyway, nothing is done without testing :)

Comment: ok, I have Edited my post with the new code I am using, Thank you MadProgrammer and Mik378 for handing me amazing pointers. I landed on the Collections.synchronizedList, since I am mostly writing to the list. Making it a thread safe operation, happy days =)